# Indicator function to zero-set of a function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given the indicator function $I_{C}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to a **convex set $C \subset \mathbb{R}$** and a function $g(x): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$ I_{C}(g(x)) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } g(x) \in C \\ \infty & \text{if } g(x) \notin C \end{cases} $$

Under what conditions of $g(x)$ is $f(x):=I_{C}(g(x))$ convex?

Let's apply the definition of a convex function:

$$ (1-\lambda) f(a) + \lambda f(b) \geq f( (1-\lambda)a + \lambda b ) ,\quad \forall \lambda \in [0,1] \text{ and } a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
We see that if

1. $g(a) \in C$  and $g(b) \notin C$,  then $\infty \geq I_C\left( g((1-\lambda)a + \lambda b )\right)$ which is always true
2. $g(a) \notin C$  and $g(b) \in C$   then we get the same as in 1. (true)
3. $g(a) \in C$  and $g(b) \in C$  then  $0\geq I_C\left( g((1-\lambda)a + \lambda b )\right)$ where it follows that 
   $$g((1-\lambda)a + \lambda b ) \in C$$

So concluding, if

$$ g(a) \in C  \text{ and } g(b) \in C \quad \Rightarrow g((1-\lambda)a + \lambda b ) \in C   \qquad (1)$$
for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$ **then
the indicator function $I_{C}(g(x))$ is convex.**

But what kind of functions fullfil condition (1)?
Is that a monotnicity condition on $g$?

Comment: Your convexity condition is actually more of a condition on $C$ than on $g$. After all, the only convex functions that are 1) defined on all $\mathbb{R}^n$ and 2) are bounded are *constant.* Think about what that means for your condition (1). For instance, what if $C=[0,1]$?

Comment: The convexity of $I_C \circ g$ is equivalent to the convexity of the preimage of $C$ under $g$, namely of the set $g^{-1}(C) := \{x | g(x) \in C\}$. A sufficient condition for the latter to be convex is that $g$ be a monotone function (w.r.t to some order on $\mathbb{R}^n$). More here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_Image_of_Convex_Set_under_Monotone_Mapping_is_Convex.

Comment: Another sufficient condition is that $g$ be an affine function.

Comment: @dohmatob: what do you mean with w.r.t some order on $\mathbb{R}^n$?